# Ghusl and nail paint on hairs

Tags: ghusl

A little while ago I was painting nail polish on my nails and my hair got in the way and I painted my 1or 2 strands of my hair and i find out a lot those hairs who got painted but i dont get them. I would do ghusl water won't pass through those strands and my ghusl will not be valid plzz help. Would it be considered a valid Ghusl ???